# How can I migrate from sbt-coveralls to GitHub Actions?

Tags: scala, github, sbt, github-actions, coveralls

I've been using Travis with sbt-scoverage + sbt-coveralls and now want to try Github Actions.

I've been able to do my coverage in my Action but the GitHub Action for Coveralls.io fails because no `lcov.info` file is generated. I'm not aware that scoverage generates `lcov.info` (does it?).

Has anyone been successful using GitHub Actions with sbt + coverage + coveralls?

Here's my action script:

```
name: My Scala CI

on: ["push", "pull_request"]

jobs:
  build:
    name: My CI
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      with:
        fetch-depth: 1
    - name: Set up JDK 13
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: '13.0.1'
    - name: Run tests
      uses: lokkju/github-action-sbt@master
      with:
        commands: '+ test'
    - name: Generate coverage report (1 of 5 - clean)
      uses: lokkju/github-action-sbt@master
      with:
        commands: 'clean'
    - name: Generate coverage report (2 of 5 - coverage)
      uses: lokkju/github-action-sbt@master
      with:
        commands: 'coverage'
    - name: Generate coverage report (3 of 5 - test)
      uses: lokkju/github-action-sbt@master
      with:
        commands: 'test'
    - name: Generate coverage report (4 of 5 - coverageAggregate)
      uses: lokkju/github-action-sbt@master
      with:
        commands: 'coverageAggregate'
    - name: Coveralls
      uses: coverallsapp/github-action@master
      with:
        github-token: ${{ secrets.COVERALLS }}
```

Comment: can you share your github actions config file?